# How do I make a resource scheduled or continuous based on a variable

Tags: terraform, databricks

I have a `databricks_job` resource which is `var.env == "dev"` I want to run on a `schedule { }`, but if `var.env == "prod"`, I want it to run `continuous { }`. So as a simple example, what I want to do is

```
resource "databricks_job" "job_1" {
  ...

  if var.env == "prod":
    continuous {
      pause_status = "UNPAUSED"
    }
  else:
    schedule {
      pause_status           = "UNPAUSED"
      quartz_cron_expression = "7 0 * * * ?"
      timezone_id            = "UTC"
    }
  ...  
}
```

I have a feeling that maybe I can do this with a `dynamic` block but I am not so sure. Maybe something like

```
resource "databricks_job" "job_1" {
  ...

  dynamic "prod_schedule" {
    for_each = var.env == "prod" ? [1] : []
    continuous {
      pause_status = "UNPAUSED"
    }
  }
  dynamic "dev_schedule" {
    for_each = var.env == "dev" ? [1] : []  
    schedule {
      pause_status           = "UNPAUSED"
      quartz_cron_expression = "7 0 * * * ?"
      timezone_id            = "UTC"
    }
  }
  ...  
}
```

Comment: yes the `dynamic` block should do it... are you getting any errors?

Comment: The main error I get is actually outside of this. I get mention of control_run_state must be specified only with continuous. So I am trying to figure out how I can optionally set control_run_state when it's prod.

Comment: Please include the `control_run_state` in your sample code.  Only thing that comes to mind is to create two `resource "databricks_job"` instead of using dynamic inside one and have the same condition control if it should be enabled or not